# Using graphics in a resume for a UI/UX design position

Tags: resume, career-switch

I am a front end developer and want to apply for the post of UI/UX designer post. I would like to include graphics in my CV. As I have seen use of graphics only in the CV of graphic designers. As it is a popular convention that CV of software developers are in plain word document format, as much as possible.

So, is it appropriate to use of graphics in CV for the post of UI/UX designer professional? Will HR consider this type of CV format?

Comment: Pro tip: if you're looking to be a UI designer, `don't use inappropriate markup `.

Comment: [Do not use in-line code spans for emphasis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) or whatever it is you're going for here. They [break screen readers](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful) among other things.

Comment: wow, some questions are like buses, nothing for ages then multiple at once.  Someone asked this yesterday and it was marked as duplicate to the existing one we'd already answered, voting to close.

Comment: Cant you just bring a portfolio of sorts?

Comment: I am working over it. However, I have already sent my 'Resume' to the inbox of HR.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, but I would recommend against it. Using a non-standard or offbeat element in a resume is kind of like the essay in a college application: if it is brilliant, it can make the difference in an acceptance, but for everybody else it only hurts them.

What you are up against is that a graphic is "stylistic", so if it rubs the reviewer the wrong way, it will be a drawback no matter how good it is. You make squares, the reviewer likes circles; there is no way to control for that kind of problem. Also, anything non-standard may seem "wierd" to the reviewer. Wierd is usually not the impression you want to make with a resume.

Special graphics and formatting may work well in a resume, but as a general rule you will have better chance of success leaving that kind of thing out.